# A definition of a struct in c

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I just have a question about this definition of a struct in the book "UNIX NETWORK PROGRAMMING" (v2, pg162)
Here it is:

```
struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex
    int buff[MAXNITEMS];
    int nput;
    int nval;
} shared= { 
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INTIALIZER
};
```

I could not understand the code after shared. What does it really mean?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The code `struct { ... } shared = { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER }` defines a struct type *and* a variable `shared` of the type of the aforementioned struct type. The part `= { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER }` then initializes this variable, its first component being `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and the rest being zero.

Comment: additional details: variable "shared"'s first member variable "mutex" is being initialized to PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER. Rest of the variables (i.e. each of the individual elements in the array buff[MAXNITEMS], nput, nval) are all initialized to zero.

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro, more info here:

[PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER Macro](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.htm)

It is used for initializing a mutex with the attributes to the default value.